# Is it possible to open Google Password Manager directly from an app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I to open directly Google Password Manager in my android app because I want users to modify some settings.

I can navigate directly to certain settings, like `android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS` or even `com.google.android.gms.settings.ADS_PRIVACY`. But is it possible to achieve such Intents directly to Google Password Manager?